# How to find sln file for a project in large git repository

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github, repository, solution

I am working in a large git repository.
I want to open a project to work on it. I know the project but I want to open it from sln file related to this project and I can't find the sln file.
Is there any way to find related sln file of a 'csproj' project?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately .csproj files do not hold references back to the .sln file, it is the other way around.

The default location for a .sln file is one folder up from the project folder and Visual Studio is also happy dropping two folders back searching for a .sln referencing the project if you load a .csproj directly. And of course it is often found in the same folder. So you would expect to find it in one of those places.

Otherwise it could be anywhere and you will have to do an old fashioned search for *.sln with contents of *ProjectName*.csproj.

Get this with `git grep`:

```
git grep ProjectName\.csproj *.sln
```

Note that I am using a regular expression, so `\.` is an escaped period in a file name.

Comment: There are many folders around the project and and many hierarchical sub folders. There are solutions but they are not lacking this project. This is second time I am encountering this problem. 
I think visual studio team should resolve this problem.
Thanks **Ben Hall**

Comment: No luck with the git grep then? That should find if there is any .sln that references the project in question if it is there. Obviously replace ProjectName with your project filename.

Comment: @MuhammadShakeel I presume this command either found .sln or proved it did not exist in the git repository? If so please could you select as correct answer. Thanks.